# Extjs4 MVC Xtemplate Error:Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, extjs4, typeerror

im a newbie in extjs.
I want to display some information in a panel.
I create a panel and when i override the tpl with data the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null " occurs.

Code:

```
initComponent: function(){
        var me = this;
        var data={
                name:'lux',
                age:'22'
            };
        var item=Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{title:'title'});
        var tpl=new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<p>Name: {name}</p>',
            '<p>Company: {age}</p>',
            '<p>Location:</p>',
            '<p>Kids: '
            );
        tpl.overwrite(item.body, data);

        Ext.applyIf(me,{
            items:item

        });
        me.callParent( arguments );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the component is not rendered yet, which means the `body` element doesn't exist. Instead, you should use the api:

```
initComponent: function() {
    var item = new Ext.panel.Panel({
        title: 'title',
        tpl: [
            '<p>Name: {name}</p>', 
            '<p>Company: {age}</p>', 
            '<p>Location:</p>'
        ],
        data: {
            name: 'lux',
            age: '22'
        }
    });

    this.items = item;
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```